# Lombok compile errors with ant?(liferay6.2)

Tags: eclipse, lombok, liferay-6.2

I am using **lombok.jar in liferay6.2** portlet application.
Kepler Eclipse IDE recognize lombok.jar.
But when I compile with apache-ant-1.9.6 I am getting Errors.

Comment: **log** cannot be resolved

Comment: Could you edit your question and paste errors you got? It may not be connected to lombok at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using lombok with intelliJ and maven, and i got the same issue compiling using a maven compile.

I would recommend you to compile by right click on the project you wish to compile, which worked for me in IntelliJ, sometimes Maven(In my case) is not able to pick the plugin from the respective IDE, i think it is the same issue with your's. Hope this helps you problem.

If you haven't installed lombok.jar by double clicking it as stated here https://projectlombok.org/download.html i recommend you to do that as well.